# Limit for number of routing addresses that can be set up for email to case?

Tags: email2case

For email to case, is there a limit to the number of email routing addresses that can be set up to create a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently isn't a limit as to the number of routing email addresses that can be set up to create a case, as per the [docs](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006071).

However, the [general email limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en) still apply. So if you had a huge number of email to case routing email addresses set up, which generated a huge volume of cases, then you would hit limits.